# Is this type of handling mobile/desktop layouts a bad practice?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm currently trying to figure out what the easiest or best method is to handle html layout on phones and desktop computers.

Right now i'm doing it like this (example):

```
    .hide-web {
      @media (min-width: ....px) {
      display: none;
     }
    }

    .hide-desktop {
      @media (min-width: ....px) {
      display: none;
     }
    }
```

HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="hide-web>
 Displaying Element1 and Element2
 <element1>/element1>
 <element2>/element2>
</div>

<div class="hide-desktop>
 Displaying Element1 and Element2 but in different positions
 <element2>/element2>
 table or whatever here....
 <element1>/element1>
</div>
```

Is this a common way to do it or is it just bad?

Comment: Not a css expert, but duplicating your html isn't a good deal. For example, if you have images, it means you are loading them twice - it will make your page slower. Small things can be put into mobile/desktop divs, but not heavier content or most of the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's a different site for reviewing your codes having its good name as [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ChiragJain in its current form, this post would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR because it lacks context. See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that same behaviour with a `display: flex;` and switch between `flex-direction: column` and `flex-direction: column-reverse`

That way you'll only have a single html structure and the changes on direction would be made on the css class.

On small projects it may not be a problem, but as it grows, duplicating the structure can cause tons of headaches.

Comment: You don't have to use flex for both small and large viewports. Just whichever one gets the alternate content order.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use bootstrap display property

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/